# how to increment between a range of dates using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to increment between a range of dates using javascript. I have start_date and end_date in the following format.

```
var start_date = Fri Nov 09 2012
var end_date = Thu Nov 15 2012
```

I need to call a function which accepts all the dates by looping between start dates and end dates as parameter. Something like this

```
for (date = start_date; date < end_date; date++) {
    getCellFromDate(date, calInstance);
}
```

I need to provide the parameters to getCellFromDate in the same date format(Fri Nov 09 2012) . How do I achieve this..I am new to javascript.. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do the iteration in pure JavaScript, without the aid of any other date library, you can change

```
date++
```

to

```
date = new Date(date.getTime() + 86400000)
```

That will go to the next day at the same time.  There are 86400000 milliseconds in a day.

This will iterate through date objects.  You will need to use a date formatter and parser to go back and forth between date objects and strings.  There are many ways to do this.  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/formatting-a-date-in-javascript) for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
```

Works for any number of days, negative and positive:

```
function addDays(date, count) {
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use some date libraries. It helps you in more functions
some advanced and commonly used date libraries are

- http://code.google.com/p/datejs/
- http://momentjs.com/